# Hardy Littlewood maximal function and integral comparison.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, inequality, lp-spaces

Define the Hardy Littlewood maximal function $$g^*(y)=\sup \left\{\frac{1}{|B|}\int_B|g(x)|dx:B\text{ is any open ball containing y}\right\}.$$
For given $x_i,r_i,a_i$, first I have shown that $$\int_{R^n}\sum_{i}a_i\chi_{B(x_i,3r_i)}(x)|g(x)|dx\leq C_0 \int_{R^n}\sum_{i}a_i\chi_{B(x_i,r_i)}(x)g^*(x)dx,\ \ \ \ (**)$$for some constant $C_0$ only depending on n. Here $C_0$ can be chosen like $3^n$.

Then I want to use $(**)$ to prove the following inequality:$$\left\lVert\sum_{i}a_i\chi_{B(x_i,3r_i)}\right\rVert_{L^p}\leq C_1\left\lVert\sum_{i}a_i\chi_{B(x_i,r_i)}\right\rVert_{L^p}\ \ \ \ \ \  (***)$$
for some constant $C_1$ is independent of $a_i$'s.
I don't know how to prove $(***)$

Comment: (**) is not hard to prove. How to use (**) to prove (***)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An inequality of $L^p$ norms of linear combinations of characteristic functions of balls](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/807426/an-inequality-of-lp-norms-of-linear-combinations-of-characteristic-functions)