# An inequality between integrals of series of characteristic functions of cubes

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, measure-theory, harmonic-analysis

Let $1\leq p<\infty$. Prove that there exists $C>0$ such that 
$$
\left(\int\left|\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i\chi_{2Q_i}\right|^p \, dx\right)^{1/p} \leq  C\left(\int\left|\sum_{i=1}^\infty |a_i|\chi_{Q_i}\right|^p \, dx\right)^{1/p}.
$$
Here $\{a_i\}$ is a sequence of real numbers and $\{Q_i\}$ is a sequence of cubes in $\mathbb{R}^n$,  $2Q_i$ is the cube with the same center as $Q_i$ but twice its length.

How to prove this? Thanks.

Comment: What happens to the volume of the cube when you double its side length? The other main catch is, what happens to the overlap between the $Q_i$ when you double the lengths?

Comment: There was a very similar question answered here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/807426/an-inequality-of-lp-norms-of-linear-combinations-of-characteristic-functions?rq=1

I would like to know if one could do this for $p<1$